# How do I troubleshoot a process that kills GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, process-management, troubleshooting, evolution, pureos

Whenever I `killall evolution` and occasionally when I use the GUI to quit, I am kicked out of my GNOME Shell session and have to log in again.

I obviously want to determine the cause but I don't know where to start. How can I monitor and log GNOME Shell activity independently of my current desktop session?

(I'm running PureOS 8.0 so any Debian-based solution should work.)

Comment: Switch to a different VTTY with Ctrl-Alt + a function key (eg. F2).  That will give you a terminal session that is independent of your gnome shell.  From there you can open the gnome logs, etc.  The shell is probably running on VTTY1, so you can switch back to it with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that Evolution starts doing something when terminating, and that leaks memory, and therefore, the system kills Gnome.

1. Check `/var/log/syslog/`, it could contain a note about Gnome being killed.
2. AFAIK, evolution is no special app. It might have some Gnome extension though which might crash
3. Try to observe the memory usage when killing Evolution. It may go quite quickly if it's a bug.
4. Try to enlarge swap file to a lot, just to try if it's a memory issue.

If nothing helps - well - try Thunderbird (IMHO it's way better anyway).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could start your shell in another terminal emulator, e.g. tmux, screen.

Comment: By "GNOME Shell" I mean the desktop GUI, not bash or a terminal, so I don't think that will work.

Comment: If I'm missing something please add extra steps to help me understand what you mean! :)

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I have no idea on pureos :/. Is there no option for a ~'debug enabled' session. If not and if you have sources, you could start logging them your own. Good luck